# NSPredicate in showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter

Tags: ios, bluetooth, nspredicate, external-accessory

I am using method called `showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:completion:` which is a part of External accessory framework. It just returns bluetooth devices which iPhone found and you can pick one to connect to it.

If I use this arguments: `showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil completion:nil`, it returns all devices but you can specify which devices it should returns with NSPredicate (Filter argument). So I tried to create predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS MyString"];
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:predicate completion:nil]
```

But when I run the app, there is an error something like:

> class is not key value coding-compliant for the key MyString.

I suppose that problem is with `self` word in predicate because in this case `self` means instance of current class. Am I right? How should I write a predicate if I want to get only devices that contain *MyString* in its name? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The EAAccessoryManager documentation says that the predicate is evaluated using the name of the accessory. Your problem is that you should put MyString between quotes:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS 'MyString'"];
```

Hope it helps.